# Efficient way to parse 100mb of JSON payload

Tags: ruby, json, amazon-web-services

I am running a cron job on my amazon EC2 micro instance every 12 hours. It downloads 118MB file and parses it using the json library. This of course makes the instance run out of memory. My instance has 416MB of memory free but then I run the script it drops down to 6 MB and then it is killed by OS.

I am wondering what are my options here? Is it possible to parse this efficiently via Ruby or do I have to drop down to low level stuff like C?  I can get a more capable amazon instance but I really want to know if it's possible to do this via Ruby.

**UPDATE:**
I have looked at yajl. It can give you json objects as it parses, but the problem is, if your JSON file contains only 1 root object, then it will be forced to parse ALL the file. My JSON looks like this:

```
--Root
   -Obj 1
   -Obj 2
   -Obj 3
```

So if I do:

```
parser.parse(file) do |hash|
  #do something here
end
```

Since I only have 1 root object, it will parse the entire JSON. If Obj 1/2/3 were root, then it would work as it will give me them one by one, but my JSON isn't like that and it parses and eats up 500mb of memory...

**UPDATE # 2:**
Here's a smaller version of the large 118mb file (7mb):

GONE

It's parseable, I didn't just take some bytes off from the file, just so you an see it as a whole. The array I am looking for is this

```
events = json['resultsPage']['results']['event']
```

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to split up the download into 6 or more segments and then put them back together?

Comment: 100MB of JSON text? What are you storing? The library of Alexandria? `:P`

Comment: Why are you using JSON for this? Doesn't sound like the right format for the job. Something more record oriented (even CSV) would be a better match. If you can't control the format then maybe you can manually strip off the root object to force the format into record oriented JSON.

Comment: Getting a 403 permission error on that file.

Comment: sorry about that...fixed now.

Comment: @muistooshort can you tell me is there's a library or a way to automate stripping root objects? Ofcourse the example i gav isn't exactly how my JSON data is, the actually data I need to parse is several level deep nested array in the data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything. I'd just do it by hand and then go have a few, um, "words" with whoever thought 120MB of JSON was a good idea. XML would have been a more sensible choice given the ubiquity of SAX based parsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[YAJL](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) implements a streaming parser. You can use it to read your JSON on-the-fly, so you can operate on the contents as they come in, then discard them (and the generated data structures from them) after you're done with them. If you're clever about it, this'll keep you under your memory limits.

Edit: With your data, you are really interested in pulling out portions of the JSON object at a time, rather than parsing the whole object. This is significantly trickier, and really requires that you implement your own parser. The nuts and bolts of it are that you want to:

1. Step into the events array
2. For each event in the array, parse the event
3. Pass the parsed event into some callback function
4. Discard the parsed event and source input to free memory for the next event.

This won't work with yajl, since you are dealing with one object here, rather than multiple objects. To make it work with yajl, you're going to need to parse the JSON manually to discover the event object boundaries, then pass each event object chunk to a JSON parser for deserialization. Something like Ragel could simplify this process for you.

Of course, it would be easier to just upgrade your AWS instance.

Comment: You could pre-parse the JSON with sed or something to strip the root object, and replace it with brackets, leaving you with an array of objects to operate on, rather than an object that contains a bunch of a arrays.

Comment: If you can provide the first ~500 bytes of the object, we might be able to to help more specifically.

Comment: I've updated my answer now that we've had a look at the sample data.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the detailed response. I guess I am going to have to update my aws instance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [yaji](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) can parse the json as a stream